# How to add a new link to the default register form's footer links?

Tags: hooks, login, actions, wp-login-form

I would like to add a custom link to the footer section of the register form.

How can I do this?

I am using the `login_footer` hook:

```
add_action( 'login_footer',array($this, 'add_forum_menu'), 50, 2 );
function add_forum_menu() {
    //need code to append the new items on the menu 
) );
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual question here. Please edit your question and explain what you want to do, what have you tried and what is the outcome. Your question is very fague, this probably why you don't get any response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking at the wp-login.php file and noticed that there's an action location :

```
<?php do_action('login_footer'); ?>
```

available... to use.
So

```
add_action('login_footer', 'my_addition_to_login_footer');
function my_addition_to_login_footer() {
     echo '<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">link</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: please see the image .i need to add a new item on the menu(that already have login, and password). how to add my custom link on that menu exact .

Comment: That is why I said, edit your question to exatly what you need to do.  Win only gave an answer to what he thought, because your question is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

[image]I found the solution for this problem

```
add_action( 'login_footer',array($this, 'add_forum_menu'), 50, 2 );
 function add_forum_menu() {
    require 'templates/popup.php';
 }
```

in popup.php

```
<script>
document.getElementById("nav").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<a href ='javascript:void(0)' onclick = clickpop()>custom signup</a>|");
function clickpop()
{
   window.open('register.php','name','height=500,width=500,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); return false;
}
```